# Display Child XML Elements in GridView Column in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

I have XML Doc like the following Structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <productID></productID>
        <productName></productName>
        <productDesc></productDesc>
        <productFeatures>
            <Feature></Feature>
            <Feature></Feature>
            <Feature></Feature>
        </productFeatures>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productID></productID>
        <productName></productName>
        <productDesc></productDesc>
        <productFeatures>
            <Feature></Feature>
            <Feature></Feature>
            <Feature></Feature>
            <Feature></Feature>
            <Feature></Feature>
            <Feature></Feature>
        </productFeatures>
    </product>
</products>
```

I succeeded to dispay product element in GridView, but I still looking for a way to display the inner elements in it
 as following.

```
        var bind = productsDoc.Descendants("products").Select(product => new

        { 
            productID = product.Element("productID").Value,
            productName = product.Element("productName").Value,
            productDesc = product.Element("productDesc").Value,
            productAllFeatures = product.Element("productFeatures").Element("Feature").Value,
        }).OrderBy(product  => product.productName).ToList();

        producsGrdView.DataSource = bind;
        producsGrdView.DataBind();
```

Now by notice the xml file we can see that multiple "Feature" elements belone to the same product, the relation is (many to one).

Also in the code above productAllFeatures display only the first "Feature".

My Question is:

How to load data from many to one realationship, many Features which belong to one product" into the same GridView ?

How to display all Features in producsGrdView as one Grid Column?

is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to turn `productAllFeatures` into a list of some sort, say strings:

```
var bind = productsDoc.Descendants("products").Select(product => new
{
    ...
    productAllFeatures = product.Element("productFeatures")
                                .Descendants("Feature")
                                .Select(x => x.Value)
                                .ToList()
}).OrderBy(product  => product.productName).ToList();
```

Now in the grid view you may want to use inner repeater to bind this list and display it:

```
<Columns>
...
    <TemplateField HeaderText="Features">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("productAllFeatures") %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </TemplateField>
```

I did not test it though, so some minor mistakes might be lurking

Comment: defining productAllFeatures as a list like this way will force to lose relationship with product it belongs to. Is there other way to represent it within product? then I Extract data in GridView?

Comment: How does it lose the relationship? I mean, it is still a part of the anonymous object that you use to represent the product and which you pass to grid view. Slightly edited the code to make this more explicit

Comment: it is more clear after editing your answer, it works, thanks.